# Printing the head line only on first page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have jasper report which is created by many objects.
I want the header in one object. The object may come any where in the report.
How can i print header only on the first page of the object.
Can i use print when expression if page number equals 1.
is that page no means for whole pdf report or for only single jrxml object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What does you mean anywhere in the report? If you want to print a title only once and in the first page, use the **Title** band in the jasper reports. No need of additional conditions required.

Comment: Is not good solution, Title do additional first page

Comment: "Title" is the only band which will display in first page. There is another band named "Page Header" which is displayed in all pages. Please refer this link https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/understanding-bands#:~:text=Description-,Title,-The%20title%20band